# Gutenberg: Difference between "import" and "const" for dependencies

Tags: plugins, block-editor

I know what a "constant" is and I know "import" from php. I read many tutorials I and found both types of importing dependencies:

```
import { useSelect, AsyncModeProvider } from '@wordpress/data';
```

and

```
const useSelect = wp.data.useSelect;
const AsyncModeProvider = wp.data.AsyncModeProvider;
```

both seem to work. But which one should I use?

Comment: The answer to this depends on how your code is built, how are you building your code? _Are you using WP Scripts?_

Comment: Since I don't know I guess not? You mean this? https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-scripts/

I only use a few of this imports: https://github.com/mtoensing/simpletoc/blob/3.5/src/index.js but no wp scripts.

Comment: Yes, you're using WP Scripts: https://github.com/mtoensing/simpletoc/blob/3.5/package.json#L8, update your question to mention this as it can mean the difference between an accurate and a wildly wrong answer

Answer (score 4):

`import` will import those items from a package. `const` is just an indicator that a variable is a constant, a variable that cannot be reassigned. E.g. `const number = 5;`.

In this case, these 2 lines do exactly the same thing:

```js
const useSelect = wp.data.useSelect;
const useSelect = window.wp.data.useSelect;
```

The important difference being that if you had included a copy of the data package in your bundle, then used `const useSelect = wp.data.useSelect;` it would not use that data package, it would use `wp.data` as loaded by WordPress. The same as if you had written `wp.data` in the browser console, or `jQuery(document).ready(...`

However, because you used WP Scripts, it has webpack set up not to include WordPress packages from a predefined list, and to instead use the already loaded versions. It generates a PHP file with scripts to enqueue that the built bundle needs to run.

So for your purposes, always use `import`.

Comment: Additionally, webpack/parcel can be set up in a way that you write `import` statements but it will transform them to `const` with reference to the global `wp` object. This way you can still write modern-style JS code and don't run any dangers of having mixed versions of the WP library methods.